# List of available/registered twilio voice clients

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php

I'm looking through documention but didn't find anything that can help me find registered clients to twilio voice incoming calls.

For example. I have 10 registered clients to javascript sdk, that can handle incoming calls by their identities. But on my backend I need to find out who is registered and who is not busy making another call.

Is there any endpoint or someting that can return list of users(identites, clients, devices) with their status?

Because with TwiML I can redirect incoming call up to 10 clients. But when I don't know who is ready to answer and not busy I can't redirect responsible.

Thanks for any leads.

Answer (score 2):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I'm afraid that there isn't a way to list your currently registered clients. But you have a couple of options with how to deal with this.

You could keep a list of your registered clients manually. Adding a client to the list as they log in and removing them when they disconnect.

Alternatively, you could consider using [TaskRouter](https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter/how-taskrouter-works) to keep track of this and control the passing out of incoming call tasks to available agents. Then the agents would log on and enter an idle status in TaskRouter, when they accept a call they would be busy, once the call is over they go through a wrapping up stage before you return them to idle and ready for another call.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it with another way. When the user connects a device to twilio, I put him in the presence group with WS. When the device starts calling, I put him in another presence group. On the backend, when recieving calls, I just check who is in the ready group and not in the calling one and connect him with this incoming call.